# Magento2 - Change my account label to image

Tags: magento2, xml, image, labels

I tried to change the my account link to a  image but then found that it was called in xml in `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` as **label** .

So how could I change it to image instead of label.

I also tried to add a custom block having a image in the place of my account label but it doesnt workout.

Can anyone say how to change the label my account label to a image or icon?

[image: my account link]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass an arguments in **default.xml** for add class in account link:

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link">
 <arguments>
       <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
       <argument name="class" xsi:type="string" translate="true">custom-account-link</argument>
  </arguments>
</block>
```

Then, you can add css in ***custom-account-link*** class to display image or icon.

Comment: so, Do i have to set it as background image right? @RoshanHapani

Comment: Yes.............

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to add class using xml file and add background images using css file.

Step 1: app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

My Account
               account link

Step 2: app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/css/accountlink.css

.account-link {
  background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/paper.gif");
}